# Using String (the same memory) for Map index and for Object name

Tags: c++, std

I have a Map (used as inverted index) and a list of object where each one have a name.

Is there someway to assign exactly the same space in memory for both?

something like: 
the map have the string and each object will have a pointer to a key of the map?

I want to achieve something like this.

What is the index of "String1" on the vector?
What is the string on the index 3 of the vector?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not to do such space optimization unless you really need it.

One way to do this would be to use pointers instead of objects. Safer way would be to use `smart pointer`. Your list of object would contain smart pointer of objects and you can reverse map using these smart pointers.

Comment: And how you can do that with pointers?, the only way i can think is to make the object point to the iterator of the key of the map.

Comment: No, you can not keep the address of iterators, it is unsafe. With time, your map objects may move to different memory. (You should fetch a fresh iterator when you want to use it. Storing an iterator is almost never a good idea)

Comment: and do you get the idea of how to implement what @Mohit Jain say's?, I still don't know how to do it.

Comment: but, you lost all the sense of having a map to use like inverted index, now i just can access to the map using some ptr from the vector. the idea was to be hable to say "ok, what is the index of 'string1'?, and what is the string with index = 3?"

Comment: You can make `light weight smart pointer` pointers of your own or wrap any existing `smart pointers` in your class to achieve this. A [working example here](http://ideone.com/tn3Ovi). This serves 2 objectives, avoid un-necessary memory allocation and enable mapping from string as per your requirement.

Comment: What I want to say is, in heart the idea is same about using pointers instead of actual object. Using a wrapper class, smart pointers etc are ways to make things safer and add some [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar). Safer because I think pointers are evil.